# Does Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB on mac support OpenGL?

Tags: mac, graphics-card, opengl

I need to buy a new computer for a computer graphics course that supports OpenGL. I have a Mac computer currently with Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB as the graphics card. Will this support OpenGL or should I buy another computer? If I should buy another computer, are there any recommendations for what I should get? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [What version of OpenGL do you need? OpenGL is only for legacy software so it doesn’t matter. Vulcan is actively developed.](https://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/device/Intel(R)%20HD%20Graphics%206000)

Comment: @Ramhound I'm honestly not sure, my professor did not specify. I would love to get the most recent version of OpenGL but I doubt thats possible. I was just hoping I could get any version at all that I could use in class.

Comment: OpenGL is based on **hardware** support. You must have drivers installed, that supports the operating system to allow that hardware support to be utilized.Your hardware is nearly a decade only, if you need anything other than what’s supported by the hardware, get new hardware. Your question is answerable without specifics with regards to your projects requirements.  **Note: I will not answer any questions about homework assignments.** Hardware recommendations will result in this question being closed, also impossible to give recommendations, without requirements which make migration impossible

Comment: Macs support OpenGL 2.1 & nothing newer. Macs use *Metal* not OGL. Apple dropped support for OpenGL many years ago. You need to find out *exactly* what the course requirements are, because buying a newer Mac will not gain you higher OpenGL support. Also, a new M1 Mac would not give you any kind of Intel support. You really need solid **specifics** from the school, to save you buying a very expensive paperweight.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to find out from your professor what version of OpenGL support is required by the tools your professor is going to ask you to use.

Then you can use lists such as [this GPU capabilities list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Graphics_Technology#Capabilities_(GPU_hardware)) which tells you what versions are supported by what processors. Integrated GPUs are tied to the CPU and so what version of OpenGL you need sets a minimum bar for what processor you would be looking for.

As an example if you only need OpenGL 4.0 then you would need an Intel 3rd generation (Ivy Bridge) or better CPU. Newer CPUs would support newer versions.

Comment: This doesn't work for Macs. Apple dropped most OpenGL support many years ago, allowing only legacy v2.1 to be exposed to any apps. All modern Macs rely on Metal, no matter what technically the GPU might otherwise support for OpenGL. They also don't sell Intel-based computers any more, so you couldn't do this in Boot Camp; the OP would have to switch to Win/nix-capable hardware to get anything higher than 2.1.